# installing 32-bit architecture in amd64 linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux, 32bit, amd, architecture

I'm trying to install 32-bit libraries so I can do stack smashing in a amd64 kalios.`

The instruction for installation on a x86 linux would be:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo dpkg --configure -a &&
sudo apt-get install libseccomp-dev:i386 seccomp:i386 libc6-dev-i386
```

How could I install the equivalent in a amd64 linux in order to run executables with a 32-bit architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you have *are* the instructions for `amd64`. They will allow you to run 32-bit x86 executables.

There is a mistake in the list of packages however: you should install `libc6:386`, not `libc6-dev-i386`.

Comment: My problem was that installing `libc6-dev-i386` failed to it not being found. Resolved by
installing libc6-dev as said in https://askubuntu.com/questions/947927/unable-to-locate-package-libc6-dev-i386

Comment: Ah, that might not be exactly what you’re after; you need `libc6:i386`. (That will be pulled in by `seccomp:i386` though, so you should be good to go already.)